# How can i show text in console

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, console, communication

I was trying to see if I can send a message to my console but there is an error.

I have the following line of code:

```
<script src='./js/pages/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

And at that route there is a code that I want to send to my console:

```
console.log("hello");
```

But, when I enter to my page, there is an error:

[image]

How can I resolve this error to send the message to console?

Comment: You need a webserver to run javascript.  You can get stand-alone light-weight webservers that don't need huge installations.  Run one of those and server your page from there.

Comment: One solution is to have your javascript in the `<script>` tags within the html, otherwise if you're to link an external file you'll need a server for that as @freedomn-m has sais

Comment: `enter image description here`